# ReactJS - Module not found when specifying "paths" in jsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following settings in jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to import `app-constants.js` file in my components through:

```
import AppConstants from "@constants/app-constants";
```

I seem to get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@constants/app-constants'
```

My `app-constants.js` file is located directly in the `src/constants` folder:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**

I Tried using this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

And works when calling directly onto the folders like `constants/app-constants.js`

But doesn't when I try the first method.

It would be great if someone is able to enlighten me of my mistakes.

Comment: It's 2024 and it still doesn't work. Just abandon the @constants/* and use the constants/
Seems to be the best create-react-app can do.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good and you can verify it by **intellisense** e.g:

```
import AppConstants from "@constants/";
```

it will show `app-constants` in **intellisense**.

Now the problem is that **react** is not supporting `aliases` yet, but will support very soon.

> I don't know if we will add support for aliases anytime soon. I
>   personally don't have time to work on it right now. I think the
>   current options with setting the baseUrl to . or src is sufficient for
>   tackling the struggles with relative imports. Beyond that it's just
>   personal preference like using @ instead of src as prefix.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7795